# Can phase tranformations occur with change in temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase

I know that, usually, phase transition occurs with a fixed temperature. Is there a case where this is not followed? Can phase transformations occur with changing/variable temperature?

Comment: Second order phase transitions do not have an enthalpy associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, phase transformations can occur with changing temperature. Consider the example of a liquid-vapor equilibrium in a closed system.

Since the system is closed, heat input definitely increases temperature. Further, more of liquid gets converted into vapor, which is a phase transformation.

[image: phase trasition with changing temperature]

The reasoning is that the pressure is changing. For a phase transition to occur at constant temperature, the pressure must remain constant.

Comment: Or to occur at constant pressure the temperature remain constant. The Gibbs Phase rule [Freedoms = Components - Phases + 2] explains it nicely one component 2 phases gives one degree of freedom. fixing T or P makes the system invariant.

Answer (score 1):

At a fixed total pressure, phase transformation can take place over a range of temperatures for a multicomponent vapor-liquid equilibrium system.